# Code displays (binds) data to a RecyclerView list but messes up view settings when scrolling up

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

Every time I scroll down and back up on my RecyclerView, my layouts change for the wrong items when data is changing. I'm displaying sports scores, so when the games are live is when I notice it messes up the views. I've looked at other answers to this but none have helped me pinpoint what I need to add/change to fix this, so I'm hoping by posting my code someone can show what I'm doing wrong here. Here is a dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kk0iszyuk5lnde3/AAACKr1UUfz55QyItXkrMD4Ia?dl=0) so you can see my screenshots. The pictures are alternating between me swiping down and up (except for the last two pictures, dropbox changed the order for some reason).

This is my code that binds the data to the ViewHolder (sorry for the long variable names but it keeps things clear for me):

```
public class NBAGameHolder extends GameHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    /*NOTE: ONCE A GAME BEGINS:
    /       mGameStartTimeAndHomeScore will be used to display the home team score.
    /       mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter will display the current quarter.
    /       mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem will display the time remaining in the quarter
     */

    private TextView mHomeTeam, mAwayTeam, mGameStartTimeAndHomeScore;
    private TextView mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter, mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem, mAwayTeamScore, mFinalHeader;
    private ImageView mHomeTeamLogo, mAwayTeamLogo;
    private int mGreen, mDefaultGray;

    private Context mContext;

    public NBAGameHolder(View itemView, Context context)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mContext = context;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mHomeTeam = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_name);
        mAwayTeam = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_name);
        mHomeTeamLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_logo);
        mAwayTeamLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_logo);
        mGameStartTimeAndHomeScore = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_time_home_team_score);
        mAwayTeamScore = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_score);
        mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_record_quarter);
        mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_record_time_left_in_qrt);
        mFinalHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nba_final_header_text_view);
        mGreen = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.green);
        mDefaultGray = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.darker_gray);
    }

    public void bindNBAGameData(NBAGame game)
    {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(game.getHomeTeamLogoSrc()).fit().into(mHomeTeamLogo);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(game.getAwayTeamLogoSrc()).fit().into(mAwayTeamLogo);
        mHomeTeam.setText(game.getHomeTeam());
        mAwayTeam.setText(game.getAwayTeam());

        if(!game.getHomeTeamScore().equals("") && !game.gameEnded())        //if the game is live
        {
            mGameStartTimeAndHomeScore.setText(game.getHomeTeamScore());
            mAwayTeamScore.setText(game.getAwayTeamScore());
            mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setText(game.getQuarter());
            mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setText(game.getTimeLeft());
            mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.orange));
            mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.orange));
            mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setTextSize(16);
            mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setTextSize(16);
            mFinalHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(game.gameEnded())
        {
            mGameStartTime.setText(game.getHomeTeamScore());
            mAwayTeamScore.setText(game.getAwayTeamScore());
            int homeScore = Integer.parseInt(mGameStartTime.getText().toString());
            int awayScore = Integer.parseInt(mAwayTeamScore.getText().toString());
            mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setText(game.getHomeTeamRecord());
            mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setTextSize(12);
            mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setText(game.getAwayTeamRecord());
            mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setTextSize(12);
            mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setTextColor(mDefaultGray);
            mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setTextColor(mDefaultGray);
            mFinalHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(homeScore > awayScore)
            {
                mGameStartTimeAndHomeScore.setTextColor(mGreen);    //displays winning team's score in green
                mAwayTeamScore.setTextColor(mDefaultGray);  //sets the losing team to the default dark gray color
                mHomeTeam.setTextColor(mGreen);
                mAwayTeam.setTextColor(mDefaultGray);
            }
            else
            {
                mAwayTeamScore.setTextColor(mGreen);
                mGameStartTimeAndHomeScore.setTextColor(mDefaultGray);  //sets the losing team to the default dark gray color
                mAwayTeam.setTextColor(mGreen);
                mHomeTeam.setTextColor(mDefaultGray);
            }
        }
        else                                                //game has not started
        {
            mGameStartTimeAndHomeScore.setText(game.getGameStartTime());
            mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setText(game.getHomeTeamRecord());
            mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setText(game.getAwayTeamRecord());
            mAwayTeamScore.setText("");         
            mFinalHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: A good tutorial for Data Binding + Recyclerview is [here](http://chintanrathod.com/develop_apps_faster_using_data_binding_part2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The issue is because of recycling of views.
```

So what's happening here is the properties of  a list item is observed to be associated with the properties of some other unwanted list item view.

In your case, you need to set your `TextView` properties for every view in the list item.

`Example` - If you are making the text color of a TextView green if a condition fulfills, then you need to set the Text color of the TextView in else block also to whatever the default color you want in that case.

Similarly, if   you are changing the Text size  of a TextView if a condition fulfills, then you need to set the Text size of the TextView in else block also to whatever the default size you want in that case.

Same approach needs to be followed in case you are making any view `VISIBLE/INVISIBLE/GONE`.

Above any if else if statements you can set the default properties of your views like this -

```
mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setTextColor();//Set default color here
mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setTextColor(); //Set default color here
mHomeTeamRecordAndQuarter.setTextSize(10);//Set default text size here 
mAwayTeamRecordAndTimeRem.setTextSize(10);//Set default text size here 
mFinalHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//Set all those views visible here whose visibility is being changes in any of the if-else block
```

And now you can successfully alter the properties of your views in if-else block.
So for those views whose properties are not being changed, those will still own the default properties.

Comment: Ok but I have three cases to look out for: live games, ended games, and games not started. That's how I set up the structure inside `bindNBAGameData()`. So can you give a code example on how I would achieve what you're saying, while at the same time keeping the game timeline structure?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: I finally got it working! Thanks man, your answer helped a ton, so I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Bind data inside the `Adapter` class inside `onBindViewHolder()` method
Like this :

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(NBAGameHolder holder, int position) {
            NBAGame game = itemsList.get(position);
            holder.mGameStartTime.setText(game.getHomeTeamScore());
    }
```

Comment: I'm doing that but I'm calling `holder.bindNBAGameData(game)` inside `onBindViewHolder()`. I don't think your answer works.

Comment: i just noticed that the else blocks is nested ,so @Shadab Ansari is right you should set it back to the default values inside the outer else blocks when ever the condition is false